# Is the raw output returned by PHP's hashing functions the same as pack('H*')?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

PHP's various hashing functions like `md5()`, `sha1()`, `hash()`, `hash_pbkdf2()` and `hash_hmac()` allow you to set $raw_output = false and get raw binary data.

I have put together a class that encrypts using `mcrypt` and `hash_pbkdf2`. When creating the key both of the following code work:

```
// Version 1
private function createKey($salt, $password) {
    // Hash the key
    $key = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $salt, 5000, 32, true);
    return $key;
}

// Version 2
private function createKey($salt, $password) {
    // Hash the key
    $key = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $salt, 5000);
    // Pack the key into a binary hex string
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    return $key;
}
```

They both produce the same key size but are they both doing the same thing? Is either more secure than the other given that I'm using this for cryptography?

Comment: Are you talking about side-channels or whether `pack('H*', $key);` works correctly?

Comment: I'm adding a HMAC after encryption so I think (?) it's resistant to side-channel attacks. I really want to know if the both keys above are produced in exactly the same way. I.e. is $raw_output = true the same as pack('H*') in the above context?

Comment: I looked into the code and they both are based on different functions. `hash_pbkdf2` uses `bin2hex` whereas `pack` does it's own thing to reverse `bin2hex`.

Comment: Thanks. When encrypting/decrypting is either better than the other? The example on the PHP site (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) uses pack. I don't find the example particularly well documented though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have raw binary result, you should go with `hash_pbkdf2` with `$raw_output = true`. It will generate the bytes that you want without any encoding.

`hash_pbkdf2` internally uses `bin2hex` to then encode the binary string into hex. This is an additional operation. When you then use `pack` to decode the hex into the binary string, you have yet another unnecessary operation.

Using hex output and decoding it back to binary does not improve your security. If anything, it might decrease it, because password hackers might not use these unnecessary steps.

If you're concerned whether `bin2hex` actually reverses `pack("H*")`, you should use `hex2bin` as those are [companion functions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8a0bc38535f34d2e1063e9f3e3bf356300d07331/ext/standard/string.c#L130-L186) that are probably reversing each other.

Comment: Great so just for clarity: Version 1 simply keeps it as raw binary and version 2 converts to hex and then back to binary, i.e. two wasted operations. Correct?